# Elegant multiple inheritance in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiple-inheritance

I'm currently using this pattern to create a class `C` that inherits from `A` and `B`.  I couldn't call `super().__init__` from `C` since I would have to do the same in `A` and `B`, and the unexpected parameter would cause problems at the top level.  I feel like this isn't very elegant.  What is the proper way to do multiple inheritance in Python?  I guess it is unusual to query the `mro` to find out if the superclass expects a parameter?

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, something):
        self.a = X(something)

    def method_a(self):
        self.a.go()

    def method_ab(self):
        self.a.go2()


class B:
    def __init__(self, something):
        self.b = X(something)

    def method_b(self):
        self.b.go()

    def method_ab(self):
        self.b.go2()


class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self, something):
        self.a_ = A(something)
        self.b_ = B(something)

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self.a_.a

    @property
    def b(self):
        return self.b_.b

    def method_ab(self):
        for x in [self.a, self.b]:
            x.method_ab()
```

Comment: Relevant read: [Python’s super() considered super!](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/)

Comment: In your last example you aren't using inheritance at all. I mean, yes `C` inherits `A` and `B`, but the class body is using delegation/composition(i.e. doing `class C:` wouldn't change the behaviour of the class, except for `isinstance` checks[actually it's possible to do some hacks to make them work too])

Comment: @Bakuriu: Actually, `method_a` and `method_b` are being inherited…  although I admitted that it wasn't elegant. See my solution below.

Comment: @delnan: Yes, that is totally relevant!  Most important para: “For cases where object doesn't have the method of interest (a `draw()` method for example), we need to write a root class that is guaranteed to be called before object. The responsibility of the root class is simply to eat the method call without making a forwarding call using `super()`.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I found was to use a base class to absorb the extra parameters:

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self, something):
        pass

    def method_ab(self):
        pass

class A(Base):
    def __init__(self, something):
        super().__init__(something)
        self.a = X(something)

    def method_a(self):
        self.a.go()

    def method_ab(self):
        super().method_ab()
        self.a.go()


class B(Base):
    def __init__(self, something):
        super().__init__(something)
        self.b = X(something)

    def method_b(self):
        self.b.go()

    def method_ab(self):
        super().method_ab()
        self.b.go()


class C(A, B):
    pass
```